# Getting and Setting IO Scheduler on Linux from a Program

Tags: linux, io, scheduler, system-calls

I have a absolute path (for example "/mnt/target/benchmarkTest/Run1") and I want to get the list of available IO schedulers and also set a IO scheduler for the device where this path physically resides on.

Programming-Language does not matter, lets say it is c or a bash-script.

I know that you can set the IO scheduler using the `/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` file on the `sysfs` filesystem.

I know that I can get the pyhsical devices block device using

```
readlink -f `df -T -P /mnt/target/benchmarkTest/Run1 | awk 'NR>1 {printf $1}'`
```

This might return at least (list incomplete)

1. A typical block device whith a partition number, ex. `/dev/sda3`
2. A block device without a pration number if the data is stored directly on the device without any partitioning (USB Sticks for example), ex `/dev/sdd`
3. A device mapper block device if LVM (or similiar) is used, ex `/dev/dm-2`

For each of these return types I need to check for a different location for the IO scheduler:

1. Somehow get the device which actually contains the partition. Perhaps by throwing away all numbers and taking this as the device.
2. I can take the device directly into the `sysfs` file
3. Now it becomes tricky: I need to check which devices (might be many) the lvm volume resides on and then set the scheduler for each of them. Keep in mind: LVM does NOT have its own IO scheduler.

Can this process be simplified somehow? Is there a kernel syscall for this or another entrypoint which simplifies the process? The current approach seems to be very error-prone.

Thanks!